# UICollectionView Custom Cell Refreshes automatically when i Scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an `UICollectionView` and Custom `UICollectionViewCell`, where i'm loading images, when i scroll the `UICollectionView`, i'm seeing all the cells are refreshing, here is the code for `UICollectionView` **delegates**,

In `ViewDidLoad` adding this first for adding CustomCell

```
 -(void)ViewdidLoad{
      UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NMCFAIPadWishListCell" bundle:nil];
     [self.accountDetailsCollectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
  }

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      return [[self wishListData] count];

}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

       NMCFAIPadWishListCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
      [cell setWishList:[[self wishListData] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] delegate:self];
      return cell;
}
```

In **setWishList** method just assigning the values from the array to label and i have a button in `Xib` for each cell in my custom `UICollectionViewCell`, when user taps on that button i'm just changing the label BG color

```
 - (void)setWishList:(NSString*)product delegate:(id)delegate
{
      self.label.text = product;
}
```

Below is the button action

```
- (IBAction)editProduct:(id)sender
{
      self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

**Here my problem is when i scroll the Custom Cell and tap on Button in any Cell the label BG is not only changing in current cell but also in MANY CELLS.**

Answer (score 1):

You should not attempt to store any state in/on your cells as the cell objects themselves are reused at the discretion of the UICollectionView.

One solution to your problem could be:

- In your `editProduct:` method (assuming your `editProduct:` method is in your custom `UICollectionViewCell` implementation), inform the collection view’s controller that the user has “selected” that product via a protocol method (or block or some other messaging mechanism).
- In your view controller, when receiving the above message, identify the index of the cell for which the button has been tapped ([`indexPathForCell:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/indexPathForCell%3a) might be useful here) and store the fact that the item at index *n* has been selected. An NSArray might be useful here.
- In the same method, force a reload of the cell that has been tapped with [`reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/reloadItemsAtIndexPaths%3a) or a similar method. This will force the `collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to be called.
- Implement something like the following in your `collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

  ```
  BOOL itemSelected = ((NSNumber *)isProductSelectedArray[indexPath.row]).boolValue; // You can't store `BOOL`s directly into NSArrays. So I've assumed an NSNumber here.
  cell.backgroundColor = itemSelected ? [UIColor redColor] : [UIColor clearColor] // Or some other color to indicate non-selection.
  ```

As an aside, if you declare “`ViewdidLoad`” instead of “`viewDidLoad`”, you might find your code doesn’t behave the way you intend. Don’t forget to call [super viewDidLoad] somewhere in your implementation too.

Finally, I recommend getting a better handle on the concept of cell reuse by reading the “[Collection View Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewBasics/CollectionViewBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH2-SW1)” chapter of Apple’s “Collection View Programming Guide for iOS” - specifically the section titled “Reusable Views Improve Performance”.

Answer (score 1):

Cells do not maintain a state. An array of objects that correspond to the cells should main the state since cells are recycled very often. For instance, inside you cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
....

BOOL isWishListSet = self.isWishListSetArray[indexPath.row];
UIColor *cellColor = [UIColor redColor];
if (isWishListSet) {
    cellColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
cell.backgroundColor = cellColor;

....
```

**EDIT 1:**

As gavdotnet mentions in his answer, cell states should be held in a parallel array, not in the cell itself. So you would have one array that holds the data you want to show and another that holds the state of whether the cell has been selected to be on the wishlist:

```
@interface WishListViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *wishListData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *wishListStatus;

@end

@implementation WishListViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize arrays
    self.wishListData = [NSArray array];
    self.wishListStatus = [NSMutableArray array];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.wishListData.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSNumber *isWishListSet = self.wishListStatus[indexPath.row];
    UIColor *cellColor = [UIColor redColor];
    if (isWishListSet.boolValue) {
        cellColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = cellColor;
    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSNumber *isWishListSet = self.wishListStatus[indexPath.row];
    if (isWishListSet.boolValue) {
        isWishListSet = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    } else {
        isWishListSet = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    }
    [self.wishListStatus replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:isWishListSet];
    UIColor *cellColor = [UIColor redColor];
    if (isWishListSet.boolValue) {
        cellColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = cellColor;
}
```

The section

```
UIColor *cellColor = [UIColor redColor];
if (isWishListSet.boolValue) {
    cellColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
cell.backgroundColor = cellColor;
```

is repeated, so it should be in its own method, but that is up to you decide really. The example shows your data array, which populates the cells, and your wishListStatus array which holds the status of the cell. If we were not going to dequeue cells, this would not be an issue. But since we are in this case, the status must be maintained outside of the cell.

The line you are using:

```
[cell setWishList:[[self wishListData] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] delegate:self];
```

should be changed to something like:

```
[cell setDelegate:self];
```

since the delegate is never toggled and is always set to 'self'.

Comment: Chris : Can you plz elaborate..?

Answer (score 0):

Cells are being reused because of that they are refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

CollectionView reuses cells so the multiple change of background color is the correct behavior.

To fix your problem, customize your UICollectionViewCell(NMCFAIPadWishListCell) instance as follows:

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.backgroundView = backgroundView;

UIView *selectedBGView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
selectedBGView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBGView;
```

Use the delegate method for extra selection behavior:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // Instead of button actions, use this delegate method
}
```

Check out [UICollectionViewCell Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details. UICollectionViewCell has three properties *backgroundView*, *selectedBackgroundView* and *selected* which are sufficient for your needs.